# Assembler - Load value from register instead of Immediate value

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers

Some AMD64/x86 commands expect immediate values as operands (e.g. imm8). Is it possible to use a value stored in some register (e.g. ah) instead of this hard coded value?

As example:

If I want to shift a xmm register, there is the the pslldq-command:

```
PSLLDQ xmm1, imm8
```

I have to shift it n times (whereby n is stored in a register). Is it possible to do it without conditional jump?

Comment: Are you sure there's no form of this command that take a register (possibly a general purpose one) as a second argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could emulate it with a `pshufb` and a lookup table.

```
shl eax, 4
pshufb xmm0, [lut + eax]
```

The lookup table would start with (I think)

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
80 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E
80 80 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D
```

You could also use plain old unaligned reads, and use nothing "weird": (not tested)

```
movdqa [temp + 16], xmm0
pxor xmm0, xmm0
movdqa [temp], xmm0
neg eax
movdqu xmm0, [eax + temp + 16]
```

But that may suffer from a store forwarding failure, which may cost a dozen cycles.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a jump table or an indexed branch into a repeated code section if the sections are of equal length.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such as instruction (for now) under x86.
But you can do on hardcore way:

```
    mov     cl, n                        ;n as shift count number from 0 to 31
    mov     byte ptr[@_PSLLDQ + 4], cl   ;overwrite last byte of instruction
    mfence                               ;ensure that intruction is globally visible 
@_PSLLDQ:
    PSLLDQ  xmm1, 0
```

And of coures your code momory must have write access enabled.

Comment: This will probably crash right away; what sensible OS leaves the code section writable? Even if it was, pipelining. By the time the PSLLDQ instruction is overwritten, it's been long fetched by the CPU and is waiting to be executed. Modulo that, data and code caches are distinct; if the code cache line with PSLLDQ was loaded before the overwrite, the CPU won't see the overwrite. Modulo that, out-of-order execution. In short, don't.

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev: you are probably right so I have added `MFENCE` instuction.